# Unable to update file in Apache using POST method

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

I want to update a file in Apache server using POST method. I did the following things in virtual host configuration file:

```
Alias /csp1 /opt/data/logs/csp
<Directory /opt/data/logs/csp/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
Require all granted
        Require method POST GET
</Directory>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/csp_log.txt$ /csp1/csp_log.txt [PT,L]
```

I am using the `curl` command to test from the server. I can read the file but am not able to update the file.

```
curl -v -A "Mozilla" -H "Host: st-test.com"  --request POST --data '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}'  http://127.0.0.1:443/csp_log.txt

About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
> POST /csp_log.txt HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: Mozilla
> Accept: */*
> Host: st-test.com
> Content-Length: 35
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 35 out of 35 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2019 11:18:04 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) Communique/4.3.2
< Last-Modified: Wed, 20 Nov 2019 07:05:16 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 6
< Cache-Control: max-age=0
< Expires: Wed, 11 Dec 2019 11:18:04 GMT
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: deny
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains;
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
<
ttest
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work the way you think it works. Apache never writes a file just because you POSTed some contents to that file. Instead, for (most of the) static files, the request body will be discarded, and the request will be processed as if it were a GET.

If you want to upload files, you need some kind of server-side logic (for example, a [PHP file](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)), which handles the upload request, and writes the file.